# Output the array as a string with hyphen without even or odd elements

Tags: javascript, arrays

It almost works properly, but it shouldn't add the last hyphen

```
 function OmitEvenOrOdd(array, evenOrOdd) {
        let output = "";

        if(evenOrOdd === 'even') {
            for(let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
                if((array[i] % 2 === 0) && (array[i] >= '0' && array[i] <= '9')) {
                   continue;
                }
                output += array[i] + "-";
            }
        }
        else {
            for(let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
                if((array[i] % 2 !== 0) && (array[i] >= '0' && array[i] <= '9')) {
                    continue;
                }
                output +=  array[i] + "-";
            }
        }
        return output;
    }
```

Should show as on the picture
[image]

Comment: array filter with join....

Comment: Please don't post text inside images. Instead make sure the example given is a [mcve].

Comment: add check if you are at the last element, if you are not, add the dash

Comment: Forgot to mention, no any built-in functions

Comment: @YaroslavYatsyk That kind of information belongs in the question, not in the comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
function OmitEvenOrOdd(array, evenOrOdd) {
   let output = "";
   let i = 0;
   if (evenOrOdd === 'odd') {
     for (i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
       if (i % 2 == 0) {
         if (i == array.length-2) {
           output += array[i]
         } else {
           output += array[i] + '-'
         }
       }
     }
   } else {
     for (i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
       if (i % 2 != 0) {
         if (i == array.length-1) {
           output += array[i]
         } else {
           output += array[i] + '-'
         }
       }
     }
   }
   return output;
 }

 console.log(OmitEvenOrOdd([1, 'b', 'x', 2, 3, 4], 'odd'))
 console.log(OmitEvenOrOdd([1, 'b', 'x', 2, 3, 4], 'even'))
```

Comment: You could [accept](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) my answer if it is working nicely.

Answer (score 1):

You could just run through the output at the end and omit any last item that is a `-`

```js
function OmitEvenOrOdd(array, evenOrOdd) {
  let output = '';

  if (evenOrOdd === 'even') {
    for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
      if ((array[i] % 2 === 0) && (array[i] >= '0' && array[i] <= '9')) {
        continue;
      }
      output += array[i] + "-";
    }
  } else {
    for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
      if ((array[i] % 2 !== 0) && (array[i] >= '0' && array[i] <= '9')) {
        continue;
      }
      output += array[i] + "-";
    }
  }

  let tmp = ''
  for (let i = 0; i < output.length; i++)
    if (!(i === output.length - 1 && output[i] === '-')) tmp += output[i];
  return tmp
}

console.log(OmitEvenOrOdd([1, 'b', 'b', 2, 3, 4], 'odd'))
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to check if the element is the second from last:

```js
if (i < array.length - 2) output += "-";
```

I tried to change the least amount of code, so that you can still follow. Since most of the work is being done within the `if` and `else` statements, you could move those procedures into their own functions.

```js
function omitEven(array) {
  let output = "";
  for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    const val = array[i];
    if ((val % 2 === 0) && (isFinite(val) && val >= 0 && val <= 9)) {
      continue;
    }
    output += val;
    if (i < array.length - 2) output += "-";
  }
  return output;
}

function omitOdd(array) {
  let output = "";
  for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    const val = array[i];
    if ((val % 2 !== 0) && (isFinite(val) && val >= 0 && val <= 9)) {
      continue;
    }
    output += val;
    if (i < array.length - 2) output += "-";
  }
  return output;
}

function OmitEvenOrOdd(array, evenOrOdd) {
  if (evenOrOdd === 'even') return omitEven(array);
  else return omitOdd(array);
}

console.log(OmitEvenOrOdd([1, 'b', 'x', 2, 3, 4], 'even')); // 1-b-x-3
console.log(OmitEvenOrOdd([1, 'b', 'x', 2, 3, 4],  'odd')); // b-x-2-4
```

Your program can be optimized by chaining a `filter` with a `join`. You could even `xor` the boolean `isEven` flag with the result of an even check.

```js
const xor = (a, b) => ( a || b ) && !( a && b );

const evenOrOdd = (arr, isEven) =>
  arr
    .filter(val =>
      isFinite(val)
        ? xor(val % 2 === 0, isEven)
        : true)
    .join('-')

console.log(evenOrOdd([1, 'b', 'x', 2, 3, 4], true));  // 1-b-x-3
console.log(evenOrOdd([1, 'b', 'x', 2, 3, 4], false)); // b-x-2-4
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
function OmitEvenOrOdd(array, evenOrOdd) {
  const output = [];
  const odd = (num) => isNaN(num) || (num % 2 === 0) ? num : ''
  const even = (num) => isNaN(num) || (num % 2 !== 0) ? num : ''

  let fnObj = {
    odd,
    even
  };

  for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    if (fnObj[evenOrOdd](array[i])) {
      output.push(array[i]);
    }
  }
  return output.join('-');
}

console.log(OmitEvenOrOdd([1, 'b', 'x', 2, 3, 4], 'odd'));  //Output: b-x-2-4
console.log(OmitEvenOrOdd([1, 'b', 'x', 2, 3, 4], 'even')); //Output: 1-b-x-3
```

Answer (score 0):

you can also add one more `if else` condition for `array.length-1`

```
function OmitEvenOrOdd(array, evenOrOdd) {
    let output = "";

    if(evenOrOdd === 'even') {
        for(let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            if((array[i] % 2 === 0) && (array[i] >= '0' && array[i] <= '9')) {
               continue;
            }
            if(i === array.length-1){
                output +=  array[i];
            }
            else{
                output += array[i] + "-";
            }
        }
    }
    else {
        for(let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            if((array[i] % 2 !== 0) && (array[i] >= '0' && array[i] <= '9')) {
                continue;
            }
            if(i === array.length-1){
                output +=  array[i];
            }
            else{
                output += array[i] + "-";
            }
        }
    }
    return output;
}

console.log(OmitEvenOrOdd([1,'b','x',2,3,4], 'odd'))
```

or either you can do it by returning the sliced string

```
return output.slice(0, output.length-1);
```